# how to export the mongodb data to remote system

Tags: java, mongodb-java

I am exporting mongodb data into *.csv file. But the problem is i want to have the dump or *.csv file in remote system. While trying i am not geting!!

```
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
    Date date = new Date();
    String xyz=dateFormat.format(date);
    String query="mongoexport --host "+" "+ipAdders+" "+"-d SMPP -c UserMessages
   --csv         --fieldFile /root/Documents/UserMessagesFileds.txt -o"+" "+xyz+".csv";
    try {
      Process process=runtime.exec(query);
      System.out.println(query);
      System.out.println(xyz);
      if( null!=process  && process.waitFor() == 0 &&process.exitValue()== 0 ){
         System.out.println("Command executed sucessfully"); 
      }
      else{

      }
      return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
```

This code is storing *.csv file in my system but i want it in remote system like (192.168.0.139).

Answer (score 0):

You should dump the `*.csv` file on your system and then use [Socket](http://mrbool.com/file-transfer-between-2-computers-with-java/24516) to transfer files between computers.